# Time driven triggered script producing error/Disabled last run error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue with a combination of scripts that I operate. I have two scripts. The first is time triggered, which when activated sets off the second script. I will copy these scripts below:

```
function timeTriggersHWM() {
  var myCell=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Overview").getRange("AA1");
  var cellValue=myCell.getValue();    
  var time=cellValue;
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('highWaterMark').timeBased().after(time).create(); 
}
```

This script should trigger the 'highWaterMark' script when a time value is entered in Overview!AA1.

When I run the timeTriggersHWM manually, it works exactly as intended. However, the issue I am having is when I allow the timeTriggersHWM script to be Triggered. The timeTriggersHWM script triggers, however instead of successfully running the highWaterMark script as it does when it is manually triggered, it instead shows highWaterMark as 'Disabled' in red under 'Last run' on https://script.google.com/home/projects/.

This has worked in the past. Only recently has there been difficulties with this. Could someone advise what could be causing this? Thanks.

I have tried deleting the trigger, then creating again. Made no difference.

In case someone needs to see the content of the highWaterMark script, this can be seen below:

```
function highWaterMark() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('HWM');
  var nRows=sheet.getDataRange().getHeight();
  var values=sheet.getRange(3, 3, nRows, 2).getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == "");
    if (values[i][0] < values[i][1]) values[i][0] = values[i][1];
  }
  sheet.getRange(3, 3, nRows, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

I don't believe the issue is being cause by content of this script, but have included it here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function timeTriggersHWM() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id')
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('highWaterMark').timeBased().after(ss.getSheetByName("Overview").getRange("AA1").getValue()).create(); 
}

function highWaterMark() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id')
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('HWM');
  var range=sheet.getRange(3,3,sheet.getLastRow()-2,2);
  var values=range.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<values.length;i++) {
    if (values[i][0]<values[i][1])values[i][0]=values[i][1];
  }
  sheet.getRange(3,3,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: I have added this script, however the same results are achieved. 

1) I run the timeTriggersHWM script manually without a value in Overview!AA1, nothing happens: CORRECT
2) I run the timeTriggersHWM script manually with a value in Overview!AA1, the script triggers highWaterMark, and it performs the task desired: CORRECT
3) I set a time trigger to run the timeTriggersHWM every x minutes with a value in Overview!AA1, the timeTriggersHWM triggers correctly, but then doesn't run the highWaterMark script.

Comment: Instead what happens is a list of 'Disabled' errors in the executed list: https://ibb.co/5cYtrCc . So the timeTriggersHWM part of the script is working fine, but for some reason, the highWaterMark is performing differently depending on whether timeTriggersHWM is manually run or time Triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on how to sort this or what could be causing this issue?